# Can't find the location of .jpg files created by an app

Tags: java, android, file, camera, save

I'm completely new to android development and not very experienced when it comes to programming in general and I've been fiddling around with a photo-taking app described in a tutorial which can be found at https://androidkennel.org/android-camera-access-tutorial/. It works fine but I can't seem to find the photos taken by the app anywhere in my phone's file system so I'm not sure if they're actually being saved or not. Could someone explain how it works to me?

Comment: Reboot your device the look in a Gallery app again.

Comment: If the user grants the requested permissions and the app is not running on android 10 with limited scoped storage access, then the prhotos taken should appear in the main gallery under the CameraDemo folder

Comment: Quote from your link: `File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");
 
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }`. That tells you the path. Every filemager can show that path. '`..../Pictures/CameraDemo`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to find them! Looks like rebooting the device was the solution. But let's say that I'd want my app to further do something with them, how would I go about that? How could I refer in code to a picture that was just taken?

Comment: You (or de code) are already doing that by making it visible by putting it in an ImageView: `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageView.setImageURI(file);
        }`.

Comment: Ok, but what about a situation where I don't want to put it in an ImageView? Just want to read the file itself, for example in order to read a QR code off of it? Also now I see that new photos appear in my gallery ONLY after I have restarted my phone, why is that?

Comment: Reading the content from a file is pretty basic. Google a bit and you find plenty examples. And that they appear only after reboot or after waiting a few days is pretty normal too and has been reported here a hundred times and solved. So google a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As blackapps mentions in the comments:

> Quote from your link:
>
> ```
> File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
>             Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");
>  
> if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
>     if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> That tells you the path. Every filemager can show that path. '`..../Pictures/CameraDemo`. You (or de code) are already doing that by making it visible by putting it in an ImageView:
>
> ```
> if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
>      imageView.setImageURI(file);
> }
> ```